# PHP - Implode showing 1 result only

Tags: php

I'm having problem with `implode()`.
The array is from a session.
It is showing 1 result only.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
{

  $ma = array($list['id']);
  $na= implode(', ', $ma);      


}

echo $na;
```

But when I do this code

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
{

  $ma = array($list['id']);
  $na= implode(', ', $ma);      


  echo $na;

}
```

Everything shows up, except for comma as separator.
I hope anybody can help

Comment: You're overwriting `$na` on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you should be getting an array item everytime `foreach` iterates over `$this->cart->content()`, you should review you logic. At every iteration, `$ma` receives a new `array()` with just one element containing `$list['id']` value. Each iteration overwrites the previous value of `$ma`.

When it reaches `$na = implode(',', $ma);`, there is actually **not enough elements** to form an imploded list with separation, since there's no elements to separate (just the last one set for `$ma`).

EDIT: 
It may achieve what you're trying to do

```
$ma = array();
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
{
    array_push($ma, $list['id']);
}
$na = implode(', ', $ma);    
echo $na;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `concate` (`.`) your id with with comma (`,`).

```
$na = "";

foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
{

  $ma = $list['id'];
  $na .= ",".$ma;


}

echo $na = substr($na, 1, strlen($na));
```

[ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/RHohcv)

Comment: OR you can try another way as answered by @deceze

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list) {
    $ids[] = $list['id'];
}
echo implode(', ', $ids);
```

You need to accumulate all values into one array (here `$ids`), then `implode` all together after the loop.

Assuming `$this->cart->contents()` is a plain array, you can simplify that to:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($item) { return $item['id']; }, $this->cart->contents()));
```

or even:

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
$na = '';
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
{
  $ma = array($list['id']);
  $na .= implode(', ', $ma).',';      

}
echo $na;
```

To get rid of the comma at the end you can use:

```
$na = substr($na, 0, strlen($na)-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $na = '';     
 foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
 {
    $ma = array($list['id']);
    $na= implode(', ', $ma);      
 }
 echo $na;
```

Here in the above code you are overwriting the variable $na ($na= implode(', ', $ma); in this line).

```
 $na = '';
 foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
 {
   $ma = array($list['id']);
   $na= implode(', ', $ma);      
   echo $na;
 }
```

Here you are simultaneously printing whatever the value of $na is. Still overwriting $na.

```
 $na = '';
 foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $list)
 {

    $ma = array($list['id']);
    if($na == '')
    $na .= implode(', ', $ma);
    else
    $na .= ', ' . implode(', ', $ma);      
 }
 echo $na;
```

So here is the proposed solution using concatination in this line $na .= implode(', ', $ma). However this is not the complete solution.

Comment: This will raise an undefined variable.

Comment: I only meant to fix this line "$na .= implode(', ', $ma);" I was not writing complete code.

Comment: If you're not writing complete code, how do you expect to get upvotes?

Comment: This won't put a comma, to separate the items of the $list.

Comment: Yes I know your answer is better than me. @MubasharAbbas

Comment: @Daan I just meant to pin point the error, rest I assume that  inquirer will handle.

Comment: and @Daan I expect upvotes only when my answer is helpful.

Comment: @HarishLalwani: Consider editing your answer to add an explanation of what your code does (and apparently, doesn't) fix. An answer which consists of nothing but a block of code is seldom a good an answer.